# How can I control the visibility of several objects at once?

Tags: python, objects, 3d-view, viewlayers

I'd like to hide and unhide several objects at once. In particular, I'd like to toggle the eye icon on and off. The monitor icon works fine, but the eye icon doesn't work.

```
import bpy
obj_list = ["Cone","Cube","Cylinder","Sphere"]
objects = bpy.data.objects
for obj_name in obj_list:
    if objects[obj_name].hide_set:
        objects[obj_name].hide_set(False)
    else:
        objects[obj_name].hide_set(True)
```

[image]

**Q:** How can I control the visibility of e.g. `Cube`, `Cone` and `Sphere`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the *visibility state* per object (eye), you'd have to use [`Object.hide_get()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_get#bpy.types.Object.hide_get).

Also I'd suggest iterate through the objects of the *current scene in context* in this case (`C.scene.objects`) rather than all objects of the current blend file (`D.objects`).

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
candidates = ("Cube", "Camera")

# Toggle the visibility state (eye icon) per object
for obj in [o for o in C.scene.objects if o.name in candidates]:
    if obj.hide_get():
        obj.hide_set(False)
    else:
        obj.hide_set(True)
```

---

*Viewport visibility* (monitor) is just a bool hence one can use the [xor operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do) to toggle:

```
# Toggle viewport visibility state (monitor icon) per object
for obj in [o for o in C.scene.objects if o.name in candidates]:
    obj.hide_viewport ^= 1
```

Comment: I learned quite a bit from your answer.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @minia Possibly the most important part is if an object has a method `ob.some_method()` then `if ob.some_method:` will always be true. ... this being the basic issue with the question.  Will (for the last time) recommend debugging first in python console eg swap true and false or print some values.

Comment: @brockmann or without the if   `obj.hide_set(not obj.hide_get())`  also suggest this `for obj in filter(None, (scene.objects.get(name) for name in candidates)):` will be way more efficient.  Found about 5 dupes for this, think I pasted a lesser. If not Ok with close give heads up and will re-open.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER Need to work right now, get back to it later and let you know.

Comment: @batFINGER Just a minor detail: Don't you think using a generator like `(o for o in C.scene.objects if o.name in candidates)` is equal to `filter(None, (C.scene.objects.get(name) for name in candidates))`, makes it more readable... Apparently a rabbit hole and Mr. Architect even considered to remove the `filter()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Comment: Maybe a SO question. Nevermind filter could filter out in loop if None, Was thinking along the lines of 3 candidates in thousands of scene objects. One loops 3 times the other 1000.  If we turn it around 1000 candidates 3 scene object, AFAIK `if x in X` isn't that efficient either. Possibly the two way solution is to use intersection of the two sets.  Often see this in vert indices lists where `[verts[i] for i in indices]` is IMO better than `[v for v in verts if v.index in indices]`

Comment: for the OP both our methods won't throw a key error on a dud candidate name.

Comment: Agree, let's measure it. I don't have much time today unfortunately, I'll get back to it end of the week @batFINGER